# Not to follow the links on page

Tags: seo

Please suggest me, By writing `<meta name="robots" content="nofollow">`in the submaster page will include the links of master page or not? Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 example.com/master-page/sub-master-page

 AND

 example.com/master-page
```

These both are two different URLs therefore no-following links on one page will not effect the links on the other page.

You will have to include the no-follow meta tags on both the pages separately to make external links no-follow on both the pages:

```
<meta name="robots" content="nofollow"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Every page identified by a unique URL is unique and crawlers index each URL separately. Considering this fact and logic, your meta tag  on sub page will not affect the parent page.